# Unable to create custom comparator for date filter in Ag Grid Angular

Tags: ag-grid, angular9

I am looking for a way to create custom date comparator in Ag grid similar to Text comparator(Shown below).

Ag Grid version 22.1.1

```
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'athlete',
            filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                textMatcher: ({filter, value, filterText}) => {
                    const filterTextLowerCase = filterText.toLowerCase();
                    const valueLowerCase = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                    switch (filter) {
                        case 'contains':
                            return valueLowerCase.indexOf(filterTextLowerCase) >= 0;
                        case 'notContains':
                            return valueLowerCase.indexOf(filterTextLowerCase) === -1;
                        case 'equals':
                            return valueLowerCase === filterTextLowerCase;
                        case 'notEqual':
                            return valueLowerCase != filterTextLowerCase;
                        case 'startsWith':
                            return valueLowerCase.indexOf(filterTextLowerCase) === 0;
                        case 'endsWith':
                            var index = valueLowerCase.lastIndexOf(filterTextLowerCase);
                            return index >= 0 && index === (valueLowerCase.length - filterTextLowerCase.length);
                        default:
                            // should never happen
                            console.warn('invalid filter type ' + filter);
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

filterParams has a textMatcher which helps to implement custom comparator, Similarly is there any way to implement the same for date comparator?

I tried with the below method, but the filter is undefined.

```
colDefs :[

         {
            field: 'athlete',
            filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
             headerName: 'Start Date', field: 'startDate', filter: 'agDateColumnFilter', 
             filterParams: {
              comparator : (date1, date2, filter) =>{
                 //here filter is thrown as undefined 
               }
             }
           }

        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`null comparator`](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/16.0.0/javascript-grid-filtering/#filtering-null-values-in-date-and-number-filters) of aggrid to do this!

```
export interface NullComparator{
    equals?:boolean
    lessThan?:boolean
    greaterThan?:boolean
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I need to implement the custom comparator with the filter selected options like "Equal, Not Equal". Because Not Equal filter option removes the blank records, i need to preserve the blank records when i select Not Equal option

Comment: @coder12349 updated with answer

Comment: I did give a try, Null comparator with "equals" preserve blank records for both equal and not equal option, Ideally equals should not preserve blank records, only not equals should preserve un matching records with blank records. I have modified the plunker, could you please guide me on how to achieve?